# Why is this dim defined wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I have a code here that I need to create a button of, the code has to clear all data in a Row with values 2< and >20, but I get this error: Type mismatch, error code 13. When running the code in break mode it works, and thats what I find weird, hope you guys can help me out.

```
Sub ClearData()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim iCell As Range
Dim myValue As Long
Dim MyValue2 As Long

Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D2:D8000")

myValue = 2
MyValue2 = 20

For Each iCell In myRange
     If iCell.Value <= myValue Or iCell.Value >= MyValue2 Or iCell.Value = 
     Zero Then iCell.Clear
Next iCell

End Sub
```

I think I defined iCell wrong, but dont know why since I just started working with VBA.

Comment: is this entire bit `Dim myRange As Range Dim iCell As Range Dim myValue As Long Dim MyValue2 As Long` on one line next to the `sub()` bit? This can't be done. Every `Dim` statement needs to be on a new line and cannot start after the `sub()` line. But they can be stringed together in one `dim` statement like so: `Dim myrange as range, iCell as range, myvalue as long` etc.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `Dim` several times in the same statement. Change your `Dim` to: **`Dim myRange As Range, iCell As Range,  myValue As Long, MyValue2 As Long`**

Comment: This code is working for me

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the code was working for me at first, but not when I use it with a button. The dim lines are not stringed together, that was a mistake of me copy pasting.

Comment: If your code is just formatted wrong in this post, but actually works like @Dorian stated, (it worked for me too after cleaning it up) then the issue might be that you have non-numeric or blank values in the range `("SourceData").Range("D2:D8000")` which will throw a type mismatch since you are testing it against numeric values.

Comment: @Plutian I also tested with string in it but i can't reproduce this error ...

Comment: @Plutian, I think it has something to do with that, is there a way to add some code which ignores the blank cells?

Comment: The weird thing is that the codes do work, but a button on another worksheet with the sub attached to it doenst.

Comment: @JilmerRusschen, I have to agree with @Dorian I have tested it as well with any possible value I could throw in there, but the code runs as expected. The only thing I get is that `Zero` is undefined. When changing this to actual zero or any dimmed value it works as expected. Not sure why you get an error.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the above sub from the command button?

Comment: @JilmerRusschen Can you `debug.print iCell.address` and tell us the content of the cells giving you this error ?

Comment: @Plutian only when using a button on another worksheet.

Comment: This is the document, if any of you want to take a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/14S4zNl32ZE9qPxETkHabIpDt-9biM87u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it gives the values $D$D7122

Comment: Agreed with @Plutian , you need to change `Zero` to `0` in order to make it work. I also added a button to another sheet and the code runs fine from there. Can you describe the way you assigned the macro to the button?

Comment: Is `ClearData`in a Module?

Comment: @Zac Yes, the code in the question is a module.

Comment: @JustynaMK Just inserted a button and clicked the macro "ClearData" , thats it

Comment: The weird thing is that the code works with F8, but not with the run button

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your sub and then try and lick the button

Comment: The value which throws an error is a problem with the formula in cell D7122 throwing `#DIV/0`. Nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @JilmerRusschen you could create another `IF Statement` to check if `iCell.Value` is a number and if this condition meet proceed to comparison between `iCell.Value`, `MyValue2 ` & `myValue `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your document, the issue is not with your code, but with the data in your spreadsheet. As stated in the comments, the error occurs in cell D7122, which value is `#DIV/0!` Error: "division by zero" since the formula devides by the value in range B, which is not filled in so zero by default. You should change this to `=IFERROR("Insert your formula here", "")` which will display blank instead of `#DIV/0!` and not break your code.

*edited as I'm stupid and didn't see the complete formula. Answer revised.

Comment: @JilmerRusschen Phew, that's a relieve. Pro tip: when auto-filling formula's beyond where you have data, always assume that the blank data will break your formula and put a handler like the above in (`IFERROR`, `IFNA`, or `IF(cell="")`). Not only will it look cleaner, it also prevents near-impossible debugs like this one.

Comment: I will, we just started using vba on uni and we have a hard project for the amount of vba knowledge have. So i appreciate all the help ;)